# Exceptions with ReactNative and AndroidX

Tags: android, react-native, androidx

I am trying to integrate React-Native into my existing Android project and I see the exception below. I have followed all the steps written [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps).

There is nothing I can find online after hours of searching.

Here is the full exception log:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.myapplication.ReactActivity cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
    at com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule.getFragmentManagerHelper(DialogModule.java:245)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule.onHostResume(DialogModule.java:177)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext$1.run(ReactContext.java:174)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

I just have an native activity that has a button that redirects me to my ReactActivity which is exactly the same as mentioned in the integration guide above. Any help is appreciated!

MainActivity Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1212;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        }
    }

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goToReactActivity();
        }
    });
}

private void goToReactActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReactActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "You cannot open the React Native app as you have denied the permission",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

ReactActivity Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.facebook.react.common.LifecycleState;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

public class ReactActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    SoLoader.init(this, false);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setCurrentActivity(this)
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    // The string here (e.g. "MyReactNativeApp") has to match
    // the string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyApplication", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}


@Override
public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostPause(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(this, this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="com.example.myapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<application android:allowBackup="true"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
             android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
             android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
             android:supportsRtl="true"
             android:appComponentFactory="androidx"
             tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name=".ReactActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can u please share your manifest code

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to a fragment like you navigate for an activity?

Comment: @sanjeev No I am not. I just edited my question and added further details

Comment: @AyushKhare please add your imports as well..

Comment: @sanjeev Please check the edit again

Comment: @AyushKhare have you by any chance defined anything(related to fragment) in your xml particularly relating to `ReactActivity`?

Comment: There is no MainApplication.java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try....extending class ReactActivity with AppCompatActivity and import its package
  androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

Answer (score 0):

Thats when your existing libraries might be either dependent on androidX or are unable to compile.

Can you please add the previous code without using the androidX library becasuse that library might not still be upgraded to use androidX

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` //Try this

Comment: Where should I put this? I am not using any fragment. You can check my edit, I added more information

Answer (score 0):

first create a `ReactContext` instance, then create a `AppCompatActivity` object by passing in the TaskID of the RC instance

```
ReactContext reactContext = (ReactContext)getContext();

AppCompatActivity currentActivity = new AppCompatActivity(reactContext.getCurrentActivity().getTaskId());
```